# Knitr: do not comment out not evaluated code

Tags: r, knitr

I recently noticed a change in the use of the chunk option `eval`.

Take the following chunk:

```
<<Chunk1, eval = -2>>=
x <- rnorm(1)
Sys.sleep(5)
print(x)
@
```

A few compilations of my document ago this would result in the source code to be shown as it is in the created document but with the second line being ignored during evaluation. The result in the document would look like:

[image]

Now there seems to have been a change and the second line is still not evaluated, BUT it is commented out in the source code. I found the prior behavior pretty neat. Now I could as well just directly comment out the second line if I wanted to show it commented out and not evaluated.

[image]

Is there a way to get the previous behavior back?

Comment: When you say "Is there a way back" I take it you mean "Is there a way to use the old behavior where the line wasn't evaluated but also wasn't commented out?"

Comment: @Dason Correct ;)

Comment: How about `opts_chunk$set(comment = NA)`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik This will change the prefix for source code output. Will not affect the source code itself.

Comment: I mean I could write a custom source hook, but that would be a overkill I guess.

Comment: Do you remember the version of knitr when you had the output in your first screenshot? I don't think this is a recent change. This must have been there since day one. More info: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/383

Comment: @Yihui I was wondering that I cannot find a note in the changelog or somewhere else. The slides for one of our lectures are a Rnw document and I have been working on it for months now. I am 100% sure the unevaluated lines werent commented out until recently. I do not remember the version, but I do update my packages frequently (usually CRAN, rarely dev versions from Github). Would it be possible to add a global chunk option? Especially in lecture slides with multiple examples that was a nice thing.

Comment: It is not possible for now. I don't remember I have ever implemented the uncommented version. You can file a feature request to Github, but I don't really have time to implement it probably until two months later.

Comment: @Yihui OK. Is there a difference to comment out the lines not to be evaluated in the first place instead of setting `eval` numeric?

Comment: No difference. Basically all `eval = numeric` does is to comment out your code.

Answer (score 2):

As of knitr commit https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/78e4d5d003129a4d7efbec7b178e9a98222d777b

there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent this short of writing your own hook or forking and modifying.  The 'offending' code is: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/block.R#L160

One could put in an [issue](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues) asking to add the ability to control whether or not to comment out the unevaluated code.

Comment: @Yihui This was more of a git ninja type problem.  Actually just more of a "search" ninja problem haha.